# Register x64 dll using a x32 package

Tags: dll, windows-installer, installshield, regsvr32

I want to build a single MSI for both x64 and x32 systems. The MSI contains two DLLs, one of them is only installed on x64 systems (I've added `VersionNT64` condition for that), the DLL is being installed but not registered, however I've extracted COM data for the file. I think it's because of the fact that the package is x32. My question is : Is it possible to register a x64 dll using a x32 msi package?

I tried using install script but it didn't work:

```
#include "ifx.h"

export prototype register64BitPropertyHandler(HWND)  ;
export prototype unregister64BitPropertyHandler(HWND)  ;

#define REGSVR64            "\""+WINSYSDIR64^"REGSVR32.EXE"+"\""
#define REGSVR64RegParam    "/s \""+INSTALLDIR^"x64"^"IADotNetProfiler_x64.dll"+"\""
#define REGSVR64UnRegParam  "/u /s" + " \"" + INSTALLDIR^"x64"^"IADotNetProfiler_x64.dll"+"\""
function register64BitPropertyHandler(hInstall)
begin
    Disable (WOW64FSREDIRECTION);
    LaunchAppAndWait( REGSVR64, REGSVR64RegParam, NOWAIT );
    Enable (WOW64FSREDIRECTION);
end;
function unregister64BitPropertyHandler(hInstall)
begin
    Disable (WOW64FSREDIRECTION);
    LaunchAppAndWait( REGSVR64, REGSVR64UnRegParam, NOWAIT );
    Enable (WOW64FSREDIRECTION);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do a single MSI for this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx

and this, 32-bit MSIs can only contain 32-bit components:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

so it's unlikely you can make it work, and even if you did it may not be supported. Note that because this isn't something you should do, there's very little (if any at all) knowledge about how to do it or if it can actually be done.